# Service Bus Forwarding to another Service Bus

Tags: azure, servicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I need to create an architecture that receives messages from different Azure Service Bus topics. Those topics are in the same Service Bus Namespace. To do so, I can create one subscription for every topic. The architecture should be able to start receiving messages from more topics if needed.
The architecture needs to have its own Service Bus Namespace to receive messages, using queues or topics.

I don't want to create an Azure Function for every topic/subscription, Instead I want to be able to implement only one Azure Function to receive all messages from the different topics.

As an example:

I have a Service Bus Namespace "**ServiceBusNamespace1**"

**ServiceBusNamespace1** contains the following topics and subscriptions:

1. **topic1** -> subs1
2. **topic2** -> subs2
3. **topic3** -> subs3

I have another Service Bus Namespace "**ServiceBusNamespace2**"

**ServiceBusNamespace2** contains the following topic and subscription:

1. **topic4** -> subs4

**I need that topic4 receives messages from topic1 and topic2.**

I can do this with "auto-forwarding" option if topic4 is in ServiceBusNamespace1. But I need topic4 to be in another Service Bus Namespace.

Is there any way of achieving this?

I tried using Service Bus Event Subscription, but I cannot use custom schema for Event Grid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Azure Service Bus does not support cross-namespace forwarding natively. You will need to build the solution where a message is received from one namespace and sent to another.

If you want this feature, upvote the [feature request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/issues/452).